# As web developers, who is responsible for privacy policies, Ts and Cs, etc?

Tags: privacy-policy, gdpr

Judging by the number of questions related GDPR, privacy policies, etc. and the number of responses pointing to various "generators", it seems that most developers rely on generic, copy and paste then edit documents.

What do you do? Subcontract to a legal adviser? C&P?

Comment: It’s not an issue for a web developer at all. It’s a commercial issue, not a technical one, and should be done by someone from the commercial side of the business. The only issue for the web developer is ensuring that the site can technically comply with the promises made in the privacy policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the responsibility of the business owner. However, web developers can certainly help educate the client what she needs to implement on the website or app to be compliant.

For example, under GDPR, the business is the data controller and/or data processor. If your client asks you to insert the tracking code to enable behavioral retargeting on the website, you can educate the client that she needs a proper notice and/or consent from users to show personalized ads.

[image]